# Не запускается Runnable

Tags: java, многопоточность, геолокация, locationmanager

Имеется приложение с получением геолокации пользователя, всё работает, за исключением того, что в фоновом режиме получение геоданных прекращается. Предполагаю, что необходимо использовать класс Runnable
Вот код

```
       @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Проверка на разрешение передачи геоданных
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        System.out.println("the checkSP works_false"); //Сообщение о том, что нет разрешений
                        return;
                    } else System.out.println("the checkSP works_true"); // сообщение о том, что разрешения есть
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, GPS_location);
                    System.out.println("the method works"); // вывод о том, что Runnable работает
                }
            });
            }
        };
        System.out.println("the onStop works");
    }
```

При сворачивании приложения или блокировки экрана происходит запуск метода onStop и сообщение о его работе в консоль, в самом методе run происходит проверка разрешений на передачу геоданных и получение текущего местоположения пользователя. Вся проблема в том, что Никаких других сообщений, кроме "the onStop works" не происходит. Где я мог накосячить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы только создали объект Runnable. Его нужно передать потоку и запустить.

```
Thread tread = new Thread (new Runnable ...);
thread.start();
```